# Comparison operators not working correctly Xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I am making a grading App for my students, but my comparison operators are not functioning they way I expect them to.  My code is as follows;

```
float FINAL = ((_gradeyouwant - (_quarter1 * 0.2f) - (_quarter2 * 0.2f) - (_quarter3 * 0.2f) - (_quarter4 * 0.2f) - (_quarterM * 0.1f)) / 0.1f);

NSLog(@"q1 = %.2f", _quarter1);
NSLog(@"q2 = %.2f", _quarter2);
NSLog(@"q3 = %.2f", _quarter3);
NSLog(@"q4 = %.2f", _quarter4);
NSLog(@"qM = %.2f", _quarterM);
NSLog(@"qF = %.2f", FINAL);
NSLog(@"grade = %.2f", _gradeyouwant);

if ((FINAL > 4.3f))
{
    [_result setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"It is not possible to get your desired grade."]];
}else if ((FINAL > 4.0f))
{
    [_result setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"You would need to get an A+"]];
}else if ((FINAL > 3.7f))
{
    [_result setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"You would need to get an A"]];
}else if ((FINAL > 3.3f))

ETC. ETC.
```

When you look at the output with NSLog, it tells me the correct value of everything.  However, if I make it so the FINAL is 4.0, it does not print the correct string.  I was figuring that when it got to the FINAL > 4.0, it would not run that line.  But it does.  What am I doing wrong?  Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: I'm not familiar with the grading system but your comparison (FINAL > ?) is to 1 decimal place so I would recommend rounding FINAL before carrying out the comparison.

Comment: @RoboticCat, thanks for the input.  I will try that.  Although to get the 4.0 the program divides 0.4 by 0.1.  So the value should be 4.000 as many zeroes as it feels like.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty much how floats work. Google it, e.g. http://www.cygnus-software.com/papers/comparingfloats/comparingfloats.htm

The system may not be able to precisely store 4.0. It's more a limitation of your CPU and choice of data types. Using a range may very well work.

I'd use an int and emulate the decimal digits, e.g. GPA * 100.

Comment: thanks for the link.  I like your idea about using the int, it makes sense.

Comment: The int worked!  Thanks for the advice.  The floats were not being calculated the way I thought.  The link on floats was a great resource, they are much more complex then I thought!